# How to delete entries using wildcard in MySQL or PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the table which I've get I want to delete entries which are not having _01.jpg in PHPMyAdmin or MySQL

```
+----+------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id | nid  |           path            | style |           image_name_path            |
+----+------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1002 | 1234567 U14RNMT02_01.jpg  |   123 | 1234567-U14RNMT02-SM14B6_01-245.jpg  |
|  2 | 1003 | 1234567 U14RNMT02_02.jpg  |   123 | 1234567-U14RNMT02-SM14B6_02-245.jpg  |
|  3 | 1004 | 1234567 U14RNMT02_03.jpg  |   123 | 1234567-U14RNMT02-SM14B6_03-245.jpg  |
|  4 | 1005 | 1234567 U14DRYMT07_01.jpg |   123 | 1234567-U14DRYMT07-SM14B6_01-245.jpg |
|  5 | 1006 | 1234567 U14DRYMT07_02.jpg |   123 | 1234567-U14DRYMT07-SM14B6_02-245.jpg |
|  6 | 1007 | 1234567 U14DRYMT07_03.jpg |   123 | 1234567-U14DRYMT07-SM14B6_03-245.jpg |
+----+------+---------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Use NOT LIKE.  It's in the user documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with sql query. The `%` sign check the `_01.jpg` in the last of the `path` fields string.

```
delete from table_name where path not like '%_01.jpg'
```

Take a look on [pattern-matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, you run that query and see how empty the table is afterward :)

Comment: I believe that's exactly what op wants @GordonM

Comment: Thanks, your code worked like charm. But I don't know one thing, why did I got down votes on this question?

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha according to terms & conditions you have to tried first before posting the question here. And if you tried then you have to share your code too.

Comment: Removed DV after the query was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%_01.jpg'
```

Hope that will work.

Regards

Comment: My bad and also bad internet. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you brother :). I thought you were going to down vote me lol.